# Diagnose slow SQL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am not a DBA so please be patient with me...

Is it possible to turn on a trace on SQL Server which will tell me any SQL statement that takes longer than 2 seconds to execute, when it happened and what the SQL was? Is it possible to set the time to 2, 3 , 4 , whatever... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

In SQL Server Profiler, you can filter on "Duration"

[image]

(This is from the "Standard (default)" template on SQL Server 2012 RC0 Profiler)